# Padding issue on some resolutions in IE

Tags: css

My footer overflows to a new line in some resolutions in IE. I assume it's a padding issue that just pushes the contents wider than the container. It only seems to wrap like that on some resolutions, which doesn't make sense to me, since the container has a far smaller width than the resolution of the screen. Can't seem to find a solution.

CSS:

```
#footer
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4e4e4e;
    padding: 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
}
#sitemap
{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}

#left_map
{
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px dotted #ffffff;
}
#right_map
{
    float: right;
    padding: 30px 0;
}
#copyright
{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: inherit;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML (fragment):

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id= "footer">
    <div id="sitemap">
        <div id="left_map">
            <h4>Sitemap</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="right_map">
            <img src="images/footer_logo.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id= "copyright">
        <p>Copyright © 2012 Cornerstone Masons</p>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/O7fgt.png

Answer (score 0):

A few ides to consider:

- IE uses its own box model. Padding is calculated differently on IE than Moz and Webkit in regards to being added to or ignoring container width and border width in Quirks mode so make sure you have a doctype which forces IE to use standards compliant mode to avoid this hiccup.
- Make sure the screens with the overflow aren't unintentionally zoomed in at the browser level. Hit CTRL+0 on Windows or command+0 on mac to set to default zoom.
- Your padding is `padding: 0 0 0;` meaning the left padding might be reverting to the default value. I say this because IE is retarded and I wouldn't put it past it for misreading this on a particular build.

Comment: IE hasn't used a non-standard box model since IE5 12 years ago.  You should know better than that.

Comment: No, IE6+ only uses the W3C model when in standards compliant mode. That rules out IE7 default, and IE8+ if the browser doesn't like the doctype provided, etc. You should know better than that.

Comment: Standards mode is the mode everyone should be using.  No designer should ever be creating pages that use quirksmode.  Deliberately doing that is ridiculous.  The only reason you would ever want to do that if you are using a legacy design, like in a CMS.  Anyone that designs a quirksmode site without damn good reason should be run out of the business.  Claiming that this is "the default" is retarded.  Nobody with a brain designs sites without valid doctypes.  There's a reason it's called "quirksmode", because it is for legacy compatibility, not for new development.

Comment: Settle down, it happens often and it's worth mentioning.

Comment: It's not worth mentioning, because nobody should be doing it.  What's worse is that your original comment made no mention of standards mode, and just said flatly that IE uses it's own box model.  If you're going to say something like that, then point out that it only does it in quirksmode.

Comment: This is me: "Sex can spread herpes." This is you: "What? No only if you screw a Thai whore! Nobody should be doing that! We don't have a herpes epidemic. NOT worth mentioning! The veins in my forehead are about to pop again!"

Comment: No.  You what you said is equivalent to "Sex gives you herpes", not "Sex can spread herpes".  You made a absolute statement without qualification.